# DATEPART YEAR from 'yyyymmdd' Formatted Date

Tags: sql-server-2016, date-format

I'm working with a table that stores the date field as 'YYYYMMDD' and I need to filter the query by the YEAR, using the DATEPART from that same date field.

```
WHERE DATEPART(yy,'YYYYMMDD') = 2018
```

Comment: Is there any reason that you can't just use the `YEAR` function? Is your date stored using an actual date data type or is it stored as a string?

Comment: DATEPART(yy,'201080505') is the only one that I tried, and it gave me a conversion error

Comment: @MikeJones you should use 4 digit for year, like DATEPART(yy,'20180505') this will return year = 2018..  SELECT DATEPART(yy, '20180505') AS DatePart;

Comment: @MikeJones are you sure about `DATEPART(yy,'201080505')`? That’s one digit too many.

Comment: Is your date column of the correct type? Is it VARCHAR or DATE (or some variation)?

Comment: @Manngo Sorry, I fat fingered it but it should just be DATEPART(yy,'20180505')

Comment: @Manngo The date field is actually the Primary Key (PK,int,not null)

Answer (score 0):

If your date is actually stored as text it would be easier to do the following:

```
CAST(LEFT('20180505',4) AS SMALLINT) = 2018
```

This essentially will extract the first 4 characters of the date using the [LEFT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/left-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function and then convert it to a `SMALLINT`. If you don't want to convert it, you can omit that part.

As a tip, if you are applying this against every row in a data set it can cause performance problems. You should always try and avoid applying functions to every row in a table to determine equality. It would be more performant to do the below to obtain records for 2018:

```
SELECT *
  FROM MyTable
 WHERE MyDate BETWEEN '20180101' AND '20181231'
```

Comment: Wouldn’t it be lest costly not to cast the value: `LEFT('20180505',4)='2018'`?